# A variance of how much is acceptable for a column before we can use the column variable for Modelling?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics

I am trying to create a classification model. While pre-processing the data. I look at the variance in each column. This is the amount of variance in each column. I am confused on which all columns should I log transform before modelling. How much variance is acceptable? Could somebody please shed some light on this please.

```
Temparature     2.318567e-01
HR              4.747868e+02
SpO2            1.179291e+01
SBP             6.263887e+02
MAP             2.905884e+02
RR              2.794205e+01
FiO2            9.061920e+00
PaO2            1.327011e+03
PaCO2           7.466527e+01
pH              4.851681e-03
A.a.gradient    0.000000e+00
HCO3            1.358290e+01
Hb              5.337076e+00
TLC             6.326940e+07
Platelets       1.062145e+10
K               3.332203e-01
Na              4.429681e+01
Serum.Cr        1.897277e+00
Blood.Urea      7.321509e+02
Bili            3.352918e+00
Urine.output    5.157271e+05
Lactate         3.795719e+00
INR             5.362644e-01
dtype: float64
```

Comment: The variance by itself is not very useful. Try to compare the standard deviation to the mean. Also look at plot (histogram) of the data in normal and log scale to detect feature that would benefit from log transformation

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (if you decide to move it yourself, please delete this one, as [cross-posting is not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that looking only at variance of columns is mostly useful to delete columns with 0 variance.

If your column has at least minimal variance, you cannot conclude that the column is useless without further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on the priors you have on the data. There isn't an "acceptable range of variance" unless it comes with context.

For classification purposes it is best to train on as much samples as you can, but you do want to leave some for validation as @desertnaut has suggested.
buttom line: I would take the upper (say) 80% most variable columns and log transform them. The other 20% will remain for validation.